# SQL- How to write a query that returns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a DB which is simply a table with 3 columns: viewer_id, movie_id, Ranking
                                                    (INTEGER)  (INTEGER)  (TEXT)

Where a row in this table represents that a certain viewer has watched a certain movie.

I need to write a query that returns:
The id's of all viewers who have watched at least 75% of all the movies a certain viewer has watched (let's call him alex).

**I managed to something that returns all the ID's of all the viewers who watched the same movies as the given viewer:**

```
SELECT otherss.viewer_id FROM  
((SELECT viewer_id,movie_id FROM viewers_movies_rankings 
 WHERE viewer_id= 313) AS alex
INNER JOIN (SELECT viewer_id,movie_id FROM viewers_movies_rankings
 WHERE viewer_id != 313) AS otherz
ON alex.movie_id = otherss.movie_id)
```

And this code which returns the number of movies the given viewer (alex) watched:

```
 SELECT COUNT (*) AS num FROM viewers_movies_rankings WHERE viewer_id = 313
```

How can I complete this query?
I am struggling to use "group by" and how to count how many simmilar movies the other viewers have watched.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  This is tricky.

```
select vmr.viewer_id
from viewers_movies_rankings vmr cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt
      from viewers_movies_rankings vmr_alex
      where vmr_alex.viewer_id = 313
     ) alex
where vmr.movie_id in (select vmr_alex.movie_id from viewers_movies_rankings vmr_alex where vmr_alex.viewer_id = 313)
group by vmr.viewer_id
having count(*) >= 0.75 * alex.cnt;
```

You can filter Alex out of the results, but it is a good test to check if s/he is returned.

Note:  This assumes that viewer/movie paris are unique in `viewers_movies_rankings`.

Comment: Can you please explain what is vmr ?

Comment: VMR is table alias for the VIEWERS_MOVIES_RANKINGS table. Instead of typing such a long table name whenever you reference a column from it, you can use its *alias* which is shorter and improves query readability.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution using a lateral join, to get the count of common movies watched from a subquery. The count of the movies Alex has watched are also fetched in a subquery. These are both cross joined with the (distinct) set of viewer IDs.

I assumed "Alex" themselves should not be included in the result and that a person can watch a movie multiple time but that's meaningless for the calculation of the percentage.

```
    SELECT vmr.viewer_id
           FROM (SELECT DISTINCT vmri.viewer_id
                        FROM viewers_movies_rankings vmri) vmr
                CROSS JOIN (SELECT count(DISTINCT vmri.movie_id) c
                                   FROM viewers_movies_rankings vmri
                                        WHERE vmri.viewer_id = 313) a 
                CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT count(DISTINCT vmri1.movie_id) c
                                           FROM viewers_movies_rankings vmri1
                                                INNER JOIN viewers_movies_rankings vmri2
                                                           ON vmri2.movie_id = vmri1.movie_id
                                                WHERE vmri1.viewer_id = 313
                                                      AND vmri2.viewer_id = vmr.viewer_id) x
           WHERE x.c::decimal / a.c::decimal >= .75
                 AND vmr.viewer_id <> 313;
```

See it in action at [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7b01c/1/0).